# Run WCF Service with its routing in separated application domain in ASP.NET Web application on IIS

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf, wcf-routing

I've a WCF service which must be executed in a **separated application domain** (not in ASP.NET app domain).

I'd like to decouple my WCF service from my web server (IIS) because of various deployment scenarios of my application. (Note: This is a primary benefit of Owin when you're working with OWin & Web API).

I can run WCF Service **without** routing service in separated application domain, or I can run WCF Services **with** routing configured in the ASP.NET app domain and the service in a separated app domain within customized SynchronizationContext for WCF dispatch runtime.

But I'd like to use better methods.

Is it possible to run WCF service with routing in separated application domain?

Comment: By "Routing" Do you mean WCF Routing Service? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517423(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @hugh Yes, I mean WCF Routing with System.ServiceModel.Activation.Routing